# Qual a forma ideal para encerrar uma thread em C++

Tags: c++, thread

Estou tentando encerrar uma thread, mas aparece a mensagem "Process terminating with default action of signal 6 (SIGABRT)", com erro de memory leak inclusive. Quanto tento executar:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes ./thread-test
```

O código abaixo é o que estou tentando executar.

```
#include <CUnit/Basic.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>

void console(const char *message) {
    if (message == nullptr) return;
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\r\n", message);
    fflush(stdout);
}

void runNestedThread() {
    while (true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        console("Thread [B] running");
    }
}

void nestedThread() {
    std::thread threadB(runNestedThread);
    threadB.join();
}

void runThread() {
    nestedThread();
}


void testThread() {
    std::thread threadA(runThread);
    auto r = threadA.native_handle();
    std::atomic<bool> done(false);

    std::thread t([&done] {
        done = true;
    });
    threadA.detach();
    console("Starting Thread [A]");
    int s = 0;
    while (s++ < 5) std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    pthread_cancel(r);
    while (!done) std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    if (done) console("Thread [A] finished");
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    CU_pSuite pSuite = nullptr;

    /* initialize the CUnit test registry */
    if (CUE_SUCCESS != CU_initialize_registry())
        return CU_get_error();

    /* add a suite to the registry */
    pSuite = CU_add_suite("Utils", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (nullptr == pSuite) {
        CU_cleanup_registry();
        return CU_get_error();
    }

    /* add the tests to the suite */
    if (nullptr == CU_add_test(pSuite, "Test Thread", testThread)) {
        CU_cleanup_registry();
        return CU_get_error();
    }

    /* Run all tests using the CUnit Basic interface */
    CU_basic_set_mode(CU_BRM_VERBOSE);
    CU_basic_run_tests();
    CU_cleanup_registry();
    return CU_get_error();
}
```

Comment: duas possiblidade: um variável para controlar o loop da thread, ou aborta-la, a primeira parece ser a correta, e mais rápido, com certeza, a thread vai ser finalizada imediatamente ao terminar a função.